# Heroku help: ActionView::Template::Error (Permission de nied

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I get this error on heroku:

```
2011-06-01T09:13:29+00:00 app[web.1]: Started GET "/" for MYIP at 2011
-06-01 11:13:29 +0200
2011-06-01T09:13:29+00:00 app[web.1]:
2011-06-01T09:13:29+00:00 app[web.1]: ActionView::Template::Error (Permission de
nied - /app/public/javascripts/.permissions_check.6011580.1.163351):
2011-06-01T09:13:29+00:00 app[web.1]:     19:                         <meta http
-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
2011-06-01T09:13:29+00:00 heroku[router]: GET www.vinderhimlen.dk/ dyno=web.1 qu
eue=0 wait=0ms service=476ms bytes=934
2011-06-01T09:13:29+00:00 app[web.1]:     20:                 <% end %>
2011-06-01T09:13:29+00:00 app[web.1]:     21:                 <%= stylesheet_lin
k_tag "public", "rateit" %>
2011-06-01T09:13:29+00:00 app[web.1]:     22:                 <%= javascript_inc
lude_tag 'rails.js', 'jquery.js', 'vis.js', 'jquery.rateit.js', :cache => true %
>
2011-06-01T09:13:29+00:00 app[web.1]:     23:                              <scri
pt type="text/javascript">
2011-06-01T09:13:29+00:00 app[web.1]:     24: $(document).ready(function() {
2011-06-01T09:13:29+00:00 app[web.1]:     25:
2011-06-01T09:13:29+00:00 app[web.1]:   app/views/layouts/application.html.erb:2
2:in `_app_views_layouts_application_html_erb__1541079903689551625_21945980__132
3620808994783512'
2011-06-01T09:13:29+00:00 app[web.1]:
2011-06-01T09:13:29+00:00 app[web.1]:
2011-06-01T09:13:29+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Stopping process with SIGTERM
2011-06-01T09:13:29+00:00 app[web.1]: >> Stopping ...
2011-06-01T09:13:29+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited

Iceberg@ICEBERG-PC /c/rails/konkurranceportalen (master)
$
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your application is attempting to compile your javascript files into one and then cache it on the disk, which Heroku won't allow as it does not allow write access to disk. Remove the `:cache => true` from your `javascript_include_tag` line and find an alternate method to doing this for Heroku.